# Multi line LESS code comments that aren't compiled into CSS?

Tags: less

I need to have code comments in my LESS file that aren't in the compiled CSS. However id like them to be multi lined.

```
// This code comment in a LESS file wont be in the compiled CSS

/*
But id 
like to have
multiple lines commented out 
like this
*/
```

Comment: Since `/* ... */` comments are valid CSS comments Less assumes that you want them in the output too (unless you turn on output minification). So you don't have too much options here: either use `//` or always use minification options and (if you need to read non-minified CSS) convert minified CSS back to non-minified with a corresponding tool (like `csscomb` for example).

Comment: possible duplicate of [LESS Silent Multiline Comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073870/less-silent-multiline-comment)