# LESS add new rules to same previous selector / Advanced rulset injection

Tags: css, dependency-injection, less, mixins

i am kinda new to LESS, but already can see it's huge power of building huge design frameworks / systems.

I'll try to reduce my question as simple as i can, and hopefully i will got lucky with some help!

So, let's say i have build Framework (something like Bootstrap 3), that have a lot of own components, which have their own rules, variables to base etc. And than i have theme which of course can overwrite those variables to change style.

But what if i need to add some specific rules, which haven't been presented before?

```
// FRAMEWORK

@btn-font-size: 12px;
@btn-line-height: 1;
@btn-border: 3px;

.some-component .menu > .btn {
    font-size: @btn-font-size;
    line-height: @btn-line-height;
    border: @btn-border solid transparent;
}


// HERE STARTS MY THEME

@btn-font-size: 16px;
@btn-border: 6px;

.some-component .menu > .btn {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    background: @FFFFFF;
}
```

And you would ask, so what's the problem here? You should just get what you want with this approach.
But problem lays in my intention to build optimized code, which would be lot less in size, more readable, logical and won't ruin some of dependencies (so for some complex components i won't have to do some additional edits, just to add few things).

In plain simple words, i want it to compile like that:

```
// FRAMEWORK

.some-component .menu > .btn {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

So the idea is to extend framework, not to overwrite classes.
To do so i was trying all kinds of mixins, extends, variables with rulsets etc, which ain't seem to help or to be enough specific.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, because there seem to be no native LESS solution, but maybe some tricks?)

Comment: Well you can `import` the framework file with `reference` option and then add `.some-component .menu > .btn();` within your theme file's selector to kind of fetch the properties defined in the framework file and add. It would kind of achieve what you need. But if you want compressed/optimized code then it would be better to try the `--clean-css` option.

Comment: Hey man, thx for fast reaction! Reference seem to just output all CSS of theme minus framework, which ain't exaclty what i was after, but i'm not sure i've undesrtood correctly how to work this out with addition of calling class like mixin from theme, could you give example of what you've meant? I already have read about --clean-css, usually i don't trust so muh automated solutions like this, so i would prefer to write anything for the framework manually...

Comment: I was thinking of doing some stuff like writing all the framework classes as mixins on their own, and then just calling them and adding rules to previous classes as @rest which = to some variable ruleset. What do you think of such approach? And if it would work, than it would be also nice to know how to sort of self-execute mixins in framework by default, in order not to call them every here and there :)

Comment: I am a bit confused by the last part of the previous comment mate. The `.some-component .menu > .btn();` line is meant to kind of call the mixin. If you don't add this line in the theme file then using reference option would output nothing from the framework file in the theme. Also, Less by default would not combine/group selectors. My personal opinion would be to not reinvent the wheel and use the libraries as much as possible.

Comment: Hmm...Yeah but that means that i should call all the components and selectors (coz potentially i could want to inject something everywhere) from the theme, which would be a looot of calls)))) Technically it's possible, but not too handy.. And yeah, i can understand you opinion, but for me it's not an option, coz i have a lot of ideas which i haven't seen in existing design / components libraries that worth attention like Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also see: [How to keep duplicate properties in compiled CSS file when use LESS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27544448/how-to-keep-duplicate-properties-in-compiled-css-file-when-use-less/27612169)

Since Less v2 you should use the [Less Clean CSS plugin](https://github.com/less/less-plugin-clean-css) to compress the css output from Less using clean-css.

Clean-css will merge your properties automatically.

Compiling your code with `lessc --clean-css code.less` outputs:

```
.some-component .menu>.btn{font-size:16px;line-height:1;border:6px solid transparent;margin-bottom:12px;letter-spacing:.3px;background:FFFFFF}
```

Comment: Hey man, thx for your answer! Technically it will work, but i would strongly prefer not to use clean-css, and to use some hacky LESS functionality as scalpel tool.

Comment: I don't think that clean-css is hacky, before v2 it was built-in. Also see: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/930

Comment: Hmm, i haven't seen it was built-in before, sorry. Then my question is, how to strip it absolutely from all of other tasks like minification and other? All i want is just to join same selector duplicates in place of first selector in LESS, which seem to do what i want) + Will you have any advice of how to use this plugin with Sublime text 3? Right now i use https://github.com/timdouglas/sublime-less2css with node.js LESS to compile, how would i need to install and configure this plugin so it would compile this way in Sublime 3?

Comment: Indeed clean-css does not have an option like `--only-merge-selectors`. You can write your own plugin based on clean-css's code, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26537579/1596547. Possible you can set `lesscCommand: lessc --less-plugin-yourplugin` for sublime.

Comment: Ok, that sounds fairly interesting, i guess i should tweak it than! Since seven-phases-max doesn't seem to have too much enthusiazm about such functionality back as built-in) Thank you! Anyway, i hope that someone else would offer some other interesting solution, i'm still open minded for it :)

Comment: It's just the benefit/efforts ratio. Notice that you're talking about a feature to save just one selector (+2 brackets) for a framework that generates thousands of those. So yes, it would be nice to have but it's not going to be there until someone finds it to be so really important to put his own time implementing it.

Comment: Hey man, nice to see you! Well i guess main effort here is not only even to save selector + 2 brackets (it's not always single selector though), but to keep the logical codebase in place, without breaking sometimes vital component relations & ordering. This could make my Frameowrk extremely expandable, when overwriting it's theme for particular project (basicly my approach is that you can change anything that's in there + add anything on your own without having duplicate tons code). Hopefully there will be someone else to tear up this problem, coz i'm not a very rock-solid programmer yet).